# Phabricator: setup local-disk upload limit?

Tags: phabricator

I'm going to upload files in Phabricator according to [this manual](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_file_storage). But I find there's a limit 8M for local-disk storage engine in "$your_site/applications/view/PhabricatorFilesApplication/" .

I've already set `client_max_body_size 64M` in vhost server block for nginx.

Also, `post_max_size = 64M`, `upload_max_filezie = 64M` for php.

Then, restart nginx, php-fpm service.

But Phabricator still prints out

> No configured storage engine can store this file. See "Configuring File Storage" in the documentation for information on configuring storage engines.

when I upload a file which size exceeds 8M.

Also, there's no `storage.local-disk.max-size` configuration key.

How can I custom local-disk upload limit?

Phabricator 535c1a5, libphutil aa6cd8f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the engines support more than 8MB. Larger files are stored by chunking them client-side and uploading the chunks (the chunk size is currently 4MB).

Apparently, chunking only works with drag-and-drop - try that instead of using the file upload form.

Comment: Thank you. My OS only has one WM no DE, so I didn't try drag-and-drop.

Answer (score 3):

> According to the guideline: https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/configuring_file_storage/

After configure nginx and php, you need enable **Engine: MySQL** and **Engine: Local Disk**:

First of all go to the phabricator directory which you clone from `https://github.com/phacility/phabricator.git`

#### 1. Engine: MySQL

```
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set storage.mysql-engine.max-size 8388608
```

#### 2. Engine: Local Disk

```
phabricator/ $ ./bin/config set storage.local-disk.path /path/to/store/phabricator/files
```